# How to make a Soap service?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I need to create a soap service. All I have is wsdl file.

The result should be like this: someone make to my soap a request

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("my_wsdl_url").
```

and then he should can call my functions.

```
$soapClient->MyFunction($params);
```

The functions make different actions with database(insert,delete,update). And my question is: how to create a php script that will contain this functions? And how to attach him to wsdl file ?

Comment: I don't see the problem: *start programming*. If you encounter actual programming problems, you can ask them here.

Comment: ok ... i will make that php script. The problem is not in this. How will wsdl file know where is php script ? to send him the parameters

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using some existing framework.
I am not expert in PHP frameworks, haven't used any. But [this seems to be a list of few of them](http://www.phpframeworks.com/). Unfortunately there's nothing about SOAP webservices there, but I suspect some of the frameworks do focus on this topic.